# Изменить поведение декоратора для имплементации в новый модуль

Tags: python, декоратор

У меня есть класс с полем spent_times. spent_times - это лист и все методы класса записывают информацию, важную для логгирования в этот лист.

Также, у меня есть декоратор, который вычисляет время выполнения данной функции и записывает его в spent_times.

Вот так выглядит реализация декоратора:

```
def timing(message):
    def wrap(function):
        def called(*args, **kwargs):
            time_start = timer()
            spent_time = round(timer() - time_start, 5)

            if not args:
                return function(*args, **kwargs), spent_time

            obj = args[0]
            if hasattr(obj, "spent_times"):
                obj.spent_times.append("{}={:.5f}".format(message, spent_time))
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                logging.warning('Decorator allows to set spent_time attribute!')
        return called
    return wrap
```

Как можно видеть, в моем декораторе есть проверка на то, что вызывающая его функция имеет атрибут *self*.

Если имеет, то я могу записать нужную мне инфу в лист spent_times сразу, если не имеет, то декоратор возвращает время, потраченное на исполнение и саму функцию

Я использую декоратор в одном единственном модуле и второй случай (в отсутствии *self*) относится к "внешним" функциям в этом модуле, которые не являются методами класса, где определен лист spent_times, но я запускаю их внутри класса, так что реализация может быть такой:

Декларирование "внешней" функции:

```
def calc_users(requests, priority):
     # .....
```

И внутри класса, я могу запускать и обновлять лист вот так:

```
response, spent_time = calc_users(requests, priority)
self.class_obj.spent_times.append("user_calculation={:.5f}".format(spent_time))
```

что не очень хорошо, но по крайней мере работает.

Теперь, я перенес несколько функций этого класса в другой модуль и я хочу использовать декоратор timing.

Может кто-нибудь рассказать, как лучше имплементировать реализацию timing в новом модуле? Я не знаю, как обновлять лист..

Два разных модуля будут работать в одно и то же время и я не могу создать объект класса в новом модуле и передать его в качестве аргумента, потому что (насколько я понимаю) будет два объекта и spent_times корректно не обновится.

Может быть, есть способ передать ссылку на spent_times как-то? Я не хочу менять аргументы функций в новом модуле, так как в этом случае нарушится принцип единой ответственности (декоратор занимается логгированием, функция делает свое дело)

Как корректно сделать или улучшить декоратор для этих целей или как передать spent_times в новый модуль?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можете вместо списка сделать словарь списков и в качестве ключа использовать имя модуля (как вариант)    
Вообще - более гибкое решение сделать два простых декоратора у каждого одна функция чем один с двумя.
Кроме того - не очень понятно, что за время возвращает ваш декоратор... Ну точно не продолжительность выполнения декорируемой функции

Comment: очень даже понятно, декоратор совершенно точно ничего не меряет

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
def timing(message):
    def wrap(function):
        def called(*args, spent_times=None, **kwargs):
            time_start = time.time()
            out = function(*args, **kwargs)  # выполенние МЕЖДУ замерами времени !
            spent_time = "{}={:.3f}".format(message, time.time() - time_start)

            if isinstance(spent_times, list):
                spent_times.append(spent_time)
            else:
                logging.warning('Decorator allows to set spent_time attribute!')

            return out
        return called
    return wrap
```

использование

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spent_times = []

    @timing('A')
    def qwerrty(self):
        time.sleep(1)

    @staticmethod
    @timing('A')
    def asdf():
        time.sleep(2)

class B:
    @timing('B')
    def b_qwerrty(self):
        time.sleep(3)


@timing('func')
def func1():
    time.sleep(4)

a = A()
a.qwerrty()  # WARNING:root:Decorator allows to set spent_time attribute!
print(a.spent_times)  # []
a.qwerrty(spent_times=a.spent_times)
print(a.spent_times)  # ['A=1.000']
a.asdf(spent_times=a.spent_times)
print(a.spent_times)  # ['A=1.000', 'A=2.000']    

b = B()
b.b_qwerrty(spent_times=a.spent_times)
print(a.spent_times)  # ['A=1.000', 'A=2.000', 'B=3.000']

func1(spent_times=a.spent_times)
print(a.spent_times)  # ['A=1.000', 'A=2.000', 'B=3.000', 'func=4.000']
```